# Iterate through dictionary of string, customObject and call customObject initialiser

Tags: swift, string, loops, object, dictionary

I have a folder which consists of a number of json files. for example:

```
a.json
b.json
c.json
c.json2
c.json3
```

Each file contains data which I need to insert into a realm DB.
a = one type of object, b = another type of object and c.json1, c.json2 and c.json3 are all the same type of object but due to the quantity of content, they are split into 3 files.

Rather than creating a for loop for each type of object separately, I am trying to create a dictionary which I can iterate through for my second for loop.

```
var filesToProcess : [String: Object] =
["a.json" : A(), "b.json" : B(), "c.json" : C()]

    for (str, obj) in filesToProcess {
        let numFiles = FileCounter().getNumFilesStartingWith(filename : str, url : unzippedDestinationUrl)
        for i in 0...numFiles {
            var append : String = ""
            i == 0 ? (append = "") : (append = String(i))
            if let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: unzippedDestinationUrl.appendingPathComponent(str+append)){
                if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])) as? [[String: Any]] {
                    for item in array{
                        let itemJsonStr = item["data"] as! String
                        let item = obj(jsonStr : itemJsonStr)
                        DispatchQueue(label: "background").async {
                            let realm = try! Realm()
                            try! realm.write {
                                realm.add(item)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

where A, B and C are objects like so:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift
import Realm

open class A : Object {

open dynamic var _id : String = ""
open dynamic var prop1 : Int = 0
open dynamic var prop2 : String = ""

open override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "_id"
}
required public init() {
    super.init()
}

public init(jsonStr: String)
{
    if let dataDict = try? JSONSerializer.toDictionary(jsonStr){
        self._id = dataDict ["id"] as! String
        self.prop1 = dataDict ["prop1"] as! Int
        self.prop2 = dataDict ["prop2"] as! String
    }
    super.init()
}

required public init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
    super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
}

required public init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
    fatalError("init(value:schema:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

However in my for loop at line:

```
let item = obj(jsonStr : itemJsonStr)
```

I am receiving the error:

```
Cannot call value of Non-function type 'Object'
```

Is there anyway around this? Is what Im trying to do going to be possible, or should I just stick to what I have done already i.e. creating separate loops with repeated code for each type of object? Note A, B and C have different properties but are all initialised with an input string which is of type json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`obj` is an instance of an object, you cannot call it that way.

One way to implement what you want is to create a common superclass of your objects (e.g. `MyObject`), declare `init(jsonStr: String)` there and make your dictionary like this:

```
var filesToProcess : [String: MyObject] = ["a.json" : A.self, "b.json" : B.self, "c.json" : C.self]
```

then you will be able to call

```
obj.init(jsonStr: ...)
```

to creat an object.

You can achieve the same using a protocol.

Yet another way is to implement that using closures:

```
var filesToProcess: [(String, (String) -> Object)] = [
    ("a.json", {json in A(jsonStr: json)}),
    ("b.json", {json in B(jsonStr: json)}),
    ("c.json", {json in C(jsonStr: json)})
]
```

and then `obj(jsonStr : itemJsonStr)` will actually work.

(Note I have used an array of 2-tuples instead of a dictionary).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new function

```
func parse(jsonStr: String) {
    if let dataDict = try? JSONSerializer.toDictionary(jsonStr){
        self._id = dataDict ["id"] as! String
        self.prop1 = dataDict ["prop1"] as! Int
        self.prop2 = dataDict ["prop2"] as! String
    }
}
```

Instead of this line

```
//let item = obj(jsonStr : itemJsonStr)
```

You can do this

```
obj.parse(jsonStr: str)
let item = obj
```